# EF 4.1, Code First: The store generated pattern 'Computed' is not supported for properties that are not of type 'timestamp' or 'rowversion'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

everyone.

I'm trying to add an optimistic concurrency in my entities. There's a property defined in the entity class:

```
public byte[] ObjectVersion
{
    // ...
}
```

Here's configuration of this property:

```
Property(obj => obj.ObjectVersion)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
    .HasColumnName("ObjectVersion")
    .IsConcurrencyToken();
```

In run-time exception is thrown: "The store generated pattern 'Computed' is not supported for properties that are not of type 'timestamp'  or 'rowversion'". Matching database column has 'rowversion' type.

OK, let's change the configuration code:

```
    Property(obj => obj.ObjectVersion)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
    .HasColumnName("ObjectVersion")
    .HasColumnType("rowversion")
    .IsConcurrencyToken();
```

But exception is still thrown.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this might clarify the issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/adodotnetentityframework/thread/a6d182bd-5027-4793-bfd9-ef88a44ec6bc

Comment: I've read that topic. It describes a little bit different situation: 1) any custom property, which is **not** configured as concurrency token; 2) Alan_chen wrote, that issue at the ObjectContext.CreateDatabase, I'm not using it.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Thanks, you are quite right! I was inattentive when looking at the stack trace. The reason of the exception was in default database initializer: I typed wrong database name, and it tried to create database, so, I've got a situation from Ladislav's topic from MSDN. But it is **very**, **very** stupid in case of default strategy - to create database! Imagine, that admin is connecting to a database server, thinking he's connecting to the existing database. Default initializer makes the database, and then all of the connected users looking at the empty datatables... **crash**

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295847%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) shows these two methods for configuring a concurrency token:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>()
    .Property(t => t.Timestamp)
    .IsConcurrencyToken();


modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>()
    .Property(t => t.Timestamp)
    .IsRowVersion();
```

Comment: Did you mean that I have to remove ".HasDatabaseGeneratedOption()" call? Does "IsConcurrencyToken" option enough for DbContext to update value automatically from storage?

Comment: @Dennis, I cannot say for sure about `IsConcurrencyToken`, but `IsRowVersion` should update automatically.

Comment: close look at the IsConcurrencyToken and HasDatabaseGeneratedOption shown that they must be combined for normal work. And where "IsRowVersion" method from? PrimitivePropertyConfiguration class doesn't contains it.

Comment: @Dennis, it's a method on `BinaryPropertyConfiguration`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.binarypropertyconfiguration.isrowversion(v=vs.103).aspx